# Python not writing properly content to csv

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website using Selenium.
I made these nested loops to extract data from a table.
The data is printed to the console correctly, but is not written properly to the csv.

```
first_part = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/table/tbody/tr['
second_part = ']/td['
third_part = ']'

for n in range(2, row_count):
    row_data = list()
    for m in range(2, col_count):
        final_path = first_part + str(n) + second_part + str(m) + third_part
        cell_data = br.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        row_data.append(cell_data)

print(row_data)
with open('scraped_site.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    thewriter.writerow(cell_data)
time.sleep(5)
```

The output in the csv file is just some numbers:
1,4,/,0,4,/,2,0,1,6, ,1,0,:,4,5,:,2,4

The have been doing this on another site and is working properly. Any suggestions on what may be the error?

Comment: you print `row_data` but you save `cell_data` - it is two different variables.

Comment: you have wrong indentations and you save after `for`-loop so you have access only to last row.

Comment: you should use `class` and/or `id` in `xpath`  to make it shorter. You should also use `find_elements_by_xpath` with char `"s"` in word `elements` to get list with all elements at once.

Comment: `writerow()` needs list with data - if you use string then it will treats it as list of chars and it will add `,` between every char. Use list `[cell_data]` in `thewriter.writerow( [cell_data])`

Comment: I don't know how i couldn't see that. Spent a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: About the indentation: it is correct. It puts the data from only one row on a list, writes to the csv, then repeats with the following row. It is perfect now.